# Deploy on glassfish server : no suitable driver for jdbc:derby

Tags: maven, jpa, jdbc, glassfish, derby

When I try to upload a maven spring project which uses JPA (I use derby) on a server, I receive an error he didn't find an suitable driver for jdbc:derby :

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [service.LocationGuide]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:portnbr/leuvenspeaks;create=true Error Code: 0.

I used these dependecies for JPA and derby

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
   <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
   <version>10.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And my Persistence unit :

```
 <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="LocationPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <class>domain.Location</class>
      <class>domain.Story</class>
      <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:portnbr/leuvenspeaks;create=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Put derby driver into **$GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib** folder and restart server.

You can download Derby driver from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/derby/derby-driver.jar.zip)